# Created an Excel workbook in c# but charting is disabled?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a c# application that generates an Excel workbook. The problem is that when you open the workbook and click on the "Insert" menu, "Chart" is disabled. Any idea on how to enable this option when creating the workbook in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this part taken from [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Excel/microsoft.public.excel.misc/2008-05/msg03055.html).
Hope this helps...

> Sounds like you have the setting to
>   not display objects on the sheet (a
>   chart  is an object).
>   You probably
>   can't add a rectangle, either!
>   Find
>   the option  in Office/Excel Options.
>   Or easier, press ctrl/6 (not F6, 6).
>   Bob Umlas
>   Excel MVP

**EDITED:**
Another solution taken from [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=16496&page=1).

> Yes, the Shared workbook option will
>   grey out the chart wizard.
>   You would
>   have to remove the sharing to get the
>   wizard back in that workbook.

Comment: I think you're right...but how do I set that option in code when I create the Workbook?

Comment: @Leon: which is your problem, first or second?

Comment: Second. But I'm creating the workbook in code. I can't manually open the excel file and change the sharing option. I have to do that in code.

Comment: I'm really new to this kind of problem. I don't if can be solved using `ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess` property... try and let me know, I'm curious :)

Comment: Got it! (thanks partly to Marco)

You can set the "access mode" of the workbook when saving the file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx

In order for charting and other objects to be enabled, the access mode must be set to "xlExclusive"